# How would you implement this query? Recordset or Sql

Tags: sql, recordset

I just saw this question in an interview test I took few days back, I have the following table

```
Region Company Sales ratio_of_sales_in_region  percentile_in_region
 NA     A1      1000            0.25                25
 NA     A2      1000             0.25                50
 NA     A3      1000             0.25                75
 NA     A4      1000             0.25                100 
 EU     B1      2000            0.5                  50
 EU     B2      1000             0.25                75
 EU     B3      1000             0.25                100
.......
```

I need to extract the 30th percentile company and sales for each region
the result would be

```
Region  30th_percentile_company  30th_percentile_sales
NA           A2                       (1000*0.25 + 500 * 0.05)
EU           B1                        2000    (as B1 accounts for more than 30%)
```

The query would need to check for the above conditions like does a company already account for more than 30% and also take the weight for 30 percentile sales for each region.

EDIT : I have tried to explain what percentile means by adding a new column. I was confused but I saw the result table that was asked and it made it clear as to what they meant by 30th percentile

Comment: Do you mean 30th percentile companies per region in terms of sales, with sales figures? (note, plural).

Comment: yes... there may be two companies that make the 30th percentile sales company like for region NA I have taken the weight accordingly. But the 30th percentile company is only one .

Comment: Is it 30th percentile of companies, or companies who have a 30th percentile of sales?

Comment: hey, your table changed on me. your last two columns in table one need an explanation

Comment: @hamlin11 chekc the column percentile_in_region for NA both A1 & A2 make up 30th percentile but the 30th percentile company is A2.

Comment: I think you may have a misunderstanding of percentile per region. Percentile of sales would mean this: If company A has 90% of sales for Region C, then company A has a 90th percentile of sales for Region C. There's a miscommunication somewhere here, and I'm not sure what it is, if this isn't it.

Comment: Also there is some ambiguity. Does the Ratio-of-sales-per-region add up to 1.0, or does it add up to some value less than 1.0. Furthermore, do you want those with a 30% of sales, relative to the other records in the table only?  Example:  If there are two records, one with 0.15 and one with 0.25.. this adds to 0.40. Both would have over 30% of 0.40, but neither would have 30% of 1.0

Comment: 1.Yes I have not included other companies in the regions

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Region,
   MIN(Company) as [30th_percentile_company],  --potentially, two companies would from the same region would have the exact same percentile_in_region.
FROM
(
SELECT
   Region,
   MIN(percentile_in_region) as percentile_in_region
WHERE
   percentile_in_region > 30
GROUP BY
   Region
) a

INNER JOIN
   TableName T1
ON
   T1.Region = a.Region
   AND T1.percentile_in_region = a.precentile_in_region

GROUP BY
   Region
```